# How to properly use Spring Data Jpa and Hibernate in a multithreading environment？

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data Jpa with Hibernate. When in multithreading, I have a synchronized block which will save some objects. If the object doesn't exist, create a new one instead.

```
synchronized block
Student student = studentRepo.findByName(name); //student do have unique constraints on db
if(student==null){
  student = new Student();
  student.setName(name);
  student = studentRepo.save(student);
}
//outsize sync block
//logic to handle students
```

The behavior I want to have is that when Thread 1 created a student, Thread 2 should be able to find the created student instead of creating the duplicated student with same name, which in result will get unique violation.

I know `studentRepo.save` doesn't commit the student object to db right the way, but isn't that Object will be stored in memory and Hibernate will do a search in memory first and then if not found, it will go to db?  I also tried `saveAndFlush`, it also gets the same buggy behavior. The real Object I use is more complex, it has join with others.

Correct me if I am wrong. Now I just want to know how to make the saved student to be accessible between different threads so that my code will not try to insert duplicate data into the database.

Thread 1 finished save and comes out the sync block, then Thread 2 enter the block, when thread 2 execute `findByName`, I want to Thread2 to get the created student.

Is there any extra configuration I need to do to get such behavior? I am using Spring boot, everything is default, just configured datasource. Also the  code above is annotated @Bean singleton, and that class only handles business logic.

Comment: The second thread won't see the saved student until the transaction is committed (if your tranasctions use the usually default READ_COMMITTED isolation level). Using a synchronized block is not the right thing to do anyway since server applications usually run on multiple servers. Just make the transaction as short as possible, catch the constraint violation exception, and retry the transaction or signal the problem to the user, who will thus retry.

Comment: I hope this is a simplified example, because a unique constraint on a student name is really wrong. I've had a student with the same name as mine in the same class, and my name isn't common.

Comment: this is just a sample code I made up, just to show as an example. Even I try to make the transaction short, it will still get the same exception, saveAndFlush will commit the change to db right the way. On the isolation itself, which one is preferred to use on my case? Also propagation?

Comment: saveAndFlush will NOT commit your data to the database. It will perform the write operations, but data will get committed only at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Its the other way around, commit will saveAndFlush :)